# Mass Insert Custom Metadata Type Records

Tags: custom-metadata, import, data-import, cli

I'm using Salesforce CLI to import 5000 records of a custom metadata but I wasn't able to to import Label and DeveloperName together and I saw that is a limitation, so I tried utilize only Name but in this way, the DeveloperName and Label keep the same name, and I wish I could put Label like this:
TEST TEST TEST
and DeveloperName:
TEST_TEST_TEST

But what happen is that become: TEST_TEST TEST and the DeveloperName don't accept spaces. Issue that already been reported: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1425

How can I acchieve this solution, is that possible?
In the last case, I will create a customField that I could put the TEST TEST TEST, and the developerName stays TEST_TEST_TEST

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: why does the label have to have spaces?

Comment: Because unfortunately they asked to maked this way